# Populating a DataGridView with Text and ProgressBars

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, datagridview, progress-bar

I am creating a multi-threaded application in which each thread will appear as a row in my `DataGridView`. I want a `ProgressBar` in each row indicating the corresponding thread progress.

The question is, is this possible? And if so, how?

Comment: MSDN sample code for the progress bar cell in datagridview: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/769ca9d6-1e9d-4d76-8c23-db535b2f19c2 I don't see any problems in the multithreading after that.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

**I added class DataGridViewProgressColumn.cs** (source: [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/769ca9d6-1e9d-4d76-8c23-db535b2f19c2))

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;
using System.ComponentModel;
namespace Sample
{
    public class DataGridViewProgressColumn : DataGridViewImageColumn
    {
        public DataGridViewProgressColumn()
        {
            CellTemplate = new DataGridViewProgressCell();
        }
    }
}
namespace Sample
{
    class DataGridViewProgressCell : DataGridViewImageCell
    {
        // Used to make custom cell consistent with a DataGridViewImageCell
        static Image emptyImage;
        static DataGridViewProgressCell()
        {
            emptyImage = new Bitmap(1, 1, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        }
        public DataGridViewProgressCell()
        {
            this.ValueType = typeof(int);
        }
        // Method required to make the Progress Cell consistent with the default Image Cell. 
        // The default Image Cell assumes an Image as a value, although the value of the Progress Cell is an int.
        protected override object GetFormattedValue(object value,
                            int rowIndex, ref DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle,
                            TypeConverter valueTypeConverter,
                            TypeConverter formattedValueTypeConverter,
                            DataGridViewDataErrorContexts context)
        {
            return emptyImage;
        }
    protected override void Paint(System.Drawing.Graphics g, System.Drawing.Rectangle clipBounds, System.Drawing.Rectangle cellBounds, int rowIndex, DataGridViewElementStates cellState, object value, object formattedValue, string errorText, DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle, DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle advancedBorderStyle, DataGridViewPaintParts paintParts)
    {
        try
        {
            int progressVal = (int)value;
            float percentage = ((float)progressVal / 100.0f); // Need to convert to float before division; otherwise C# returns int which is 0 for anything but 100%.
            Brush backColorBrush = new SolidBrush(cellStyle.BackColor);
            Brush foreColorBrush = new SolidBrush(cellStyle.ForeColor);
            // Draws the cell grid
            base.Paint(g, clipBounds, cellBounds,
             rowIndex, cellState, value, formattedValue, errorText,
             cellStyle, advancedBorderStyle, (paintParts & ~DataGridViewPaintParts.ContentForeground));
            if (percentage > 0.0)
            {
                // Draw the progress bar and the text
                g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(203, 235, 108)), cellBounds.X + 2, cellBounds.Y + 2, Convert.ToInt32((percentage * cellBounds.Width - 4)), cellBounds.Height - 4);
                g.DrawString(progressVal.ToString() + "%", cellStyle.Font, foreColorBrush, cellBounds.X+(cellBounds.Width/2)-5, cellBounds.Y + 2);

            }
            else
            {
                // draw the text
                if (this.DataGridView.CurrentRow.Index == rowIndex)
                    g.DrawString(progressVal.ToString() + "%", cellStyle.Font, new SolidBrush(cellStyle.SelectionForeColor), cellBounds.X + 6, cellBounds.Y + 2);
                else
                    g.DrawString(progressVal.ToString() + "%", cellStyle.Font, foreColorBrush, cellBounds.X + 6, cellBounds.Y + 2);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) { }

    }
}
}
```

---

**Then I used that code to populate the GridView**

```
DataGridViewProgressColumn column = new DataGridViewProgressColumn();

kryptonDataGridView1.ColumnCount = 2;
kryptonDataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "TESTHeader1";
kryptonDataGridView1.Columns[0].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
kryptonDataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "TESTHeader22";
kryptonDataGridView1.Columns[1].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
kryptonDataGridView1.Columns.Add(column);
kryptonDataGridView1.Columns[2].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
column.HeaderText = "Progress";


object[] row1 = new object[]  { "test1", "test2", 50 };
object[] row2 = new object[] { "test1", "test2", 55 };
object[] row3 = new object[] { "test1", "test2", 22 };
object[] rows = new object[] { row1, row2, row3 };

foreach (object[] row in rows)
{
    kryptonDataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

---

And here is the result

[image]

Comment: The answer is very useful, but the source code of the first part should be attributed to MSDN: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/769ca9d6-1e9d-4d76-8c23-db535b2f19c2

Comment: if you get error `Specified cast is not valid.` then replace `progressVal = (int)value` with `progressVal = Convert.ToInt32(value)`

Answer (score -6):

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Progress" Width="*" Visibility="Visible">
  <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Progress}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
        <ProgressBar Value="{Binding Path=Progress, Mode=OneWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Height="25" />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

This helps you

Comment: @frzsombor yeah, NOT useful answer. Question is tagged windows forms not WPF. IMHO, better delete the question.