# C# DataGridView Progress cell

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagridview, progress-bar

I would like to create a DataGridView cell with a progressbar.
I found only implementations with a progressbar column instead of a cell.
So is there a way to have a progressbar only in one cell of a DataGridView?

Comment: Have you tried to implement it in a CellPainting event?

Comment: Not yet. What shoild I do on the event?

Comment: You could draw the rectangle that shows the progress. Calling dataGridView1.InvalidateCell you would make it update with some percentage and do a e.Graphics.FillRectangle with suitable values whenever you want to update the progress. What should trigger the changes and where do you want to store the state value?

Comment: The progressbar should show the user how far the DataGridView is filled by him. I think I could make it with your answer.

Comment: Sounds not too hard or far fetched. In the CellPainting event first return on all other cells including (I guess) headers (where row/columIndex are < 0) and then calculate the size of the bar in the cell... Use the e.CellBounds rectangle for this..!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Populating a DataGridView with Text and ProgressBars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646920/populating-a-datagridview-with-text-and-progressbars)