# How to define columns in datagridview programmatically?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

I`m making windows application

I added 1 button and 1 datagridview.

when click the button, data showed in datagridview from DB.

And this step, I have a question.

I want to define DataGridView Columns programmatically like this

1. First column = check box column
2. Second column = Process column(I want to bind data here)
3. Third column = Progress bar column(I`ll make this column)

SQL query is below

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as Process from Sales.SalesOrderDetail
UNION
SELECT COUNT(*) as Process from Purchasing.ProductVendor
UNION
SELECT COUNT(*) as Process from Person.Address
UNION
SELECT COUNT(*) as Process from Production.WorkOrder
```

And button click event is like this

```
private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AdvConn"].ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UP_SelectTableCount", conn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    try
    {
        conn.Open();

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(ds);
    }
    catch{}
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
    dt = ds.Tables[0];
    metroGrid2.DataSource = dt; }
```

How can I add or fix my code? please help me

Thanks.

Comment: Use `dataGridView1.Columns.Add`(*colname*)

Comment: thank you Novice. Yeah I already know how to use it. But I want to little more specific

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the data has been added to the datagridview you can write a simple function for adding a new column like this

```
private void AddNewColumns()
{
    metroGrid2.Columns.Add("newColumnName", "Column Name in Text");
    //To add values to the column you should run a foreach loop 
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in metroGrid2.Rows) 
    {
        if (row.Cells[1].Value.ToString()=="1") //Some condition or value  
            row.Cells[2].Value = "50%"; 
    }
}
```

This is just an idea about adding a column but not about adding a progress bar. But I believe this might help you because your main concern is to add a new column to the DGV. Hope this helps

For adding a progress bar column [Populating a DataGridView with Text and ProgressBars](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4647720/3796048) might help you

Comment: thank you Mohit Shrivastava.
I understand how to use it. So I`ll try it. And I also appreciate your link about progress bar!

Comment: Felt happy to help. Happy Coding. :)