# Datagridview column type

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio

We did not create columns visually in the **DataGridView** of form application. We get the data from **XML** and it creates the columns according to **XML**. We want the 5th column you see in the picture to be a **progress bar**. How do we do this in the codes you see below?

[Here image i need to add code blocks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pACAw.png)

If needed i can share all of project files. Thank you

Comment: See folowing : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewbuttoncolumn?force_isolation=true&view=windowsdesktop-6.0

Comment: thanks for answer but i was writed wrong. I need progress bar .

Comment: You can create a custom column : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/customize-cells-and-columns-in-the-datagrid-by-extending-behavior?force_isolation=true&view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Comment: Can this help you？https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646920/populating-a-datagridview-with-text-and-progressbars

Comment: no its not help me guys.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.