# How make a column colored in datagridview based on his value (%) VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, colors, datagridview, cell

i Have a datagrid with some value, so i would like to color the column with number (in percent) like the picture below.
Can someone help me (just in .net please)
Thank to all in advance

Datagridview real Example:

[image: Datagridview real Example]

Comment: That's not a trivial operation, so it's probably too broad a topic for a single question. You could do it ad hoc but I'd suggest that a custom column would be a better option, so you should look into the subject of creating custom columns and then ask specific questions as you encounter specific issues.

Comment: Thanks John...i know is not easy...btw was based on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646920/populating-a-datagridview-with-text-and-progressbars...but unluckily i'm not so good with c#...maybe someone can adapt it ?

Comment: I would suggest downloading Instant VB from Tangible Software Solutions. It will do as a good a job of translating C# to VB as you'll find. You may need some minor manual intervention.

Comment: I will John ....thanks again..... have a good day